# Delete rows from multiple tables in a single statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I've got 2 tables say `users` and `articles`, I need to delete a user and all instances of that user from articles as well but I need to do it in a single statement. So I can't say:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 1
DELETE FROM articles WHERE user_id = 1
```

Is there a way I can say something like:

```
SELECT u.name, u.id, a.user_id
FROM users u, articles a
WHERE u.id = a.user_id
DELETE FROM thistable
WHERE id = 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in two statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do that is to declare the foreign key as `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Doing so, if a `user` is deleted, all `articles` related to it will also be deleted.

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
  user_id int REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ebc19887c2697c167513a823f6414cf0)

If for some reason you're not able to change the table structure, consider using a `DELETE ... RETURNING` from `users` inside a CTE and then use the returned values in a outer `DELETE` on `articles`:

```
WITH j (id) AS (
  DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 1
  RETURNING id
)
DELETE FROM articles a USING j 
WHERE a.user_id = j.id;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1e474ebfe5f9d9d88bcb4f29d31e8044)